# SAP Pool capacity and peak limit-Mule esb

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, jco, idoc

Hi am having an SAP connector and SAP is sending 10,000 idocs parallel what can be the good number I can give in Pooling capacity and Peak limit,Now I have given 2000 and 1000 respectively any suggestion for better performance

```
<sap:connector name="SAP" jcoAsHost="${saphost}" jcoUser="${sapuser}" jcoPasswd="${sappassword}" jcoSysnr="${sapsystemnumber}" jcoClient="${sapclient}" jcoLang="${saploginlanguage}" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SAP" jcoPeakLimit="1000" jcoPoolCapacity="2000"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with **big amounts of IDocs**, the first thing I recommend to improve performance is to configure the SAP system to send IDocs in **batches** instead of sending them individually. That is, the IDocs are sent in groups of X number you define as a batch size in the Partner Profile section of **SAPGUI**. Among other settings, you have to set **"Pack. Size"** and select **"Collect IDocs"** as Output Mode.

[image]

> If you are not familiar with SAPGUI, request your SAP Admin to configure it for you.

Aditionally, to extract the most out of the **connection pooling** from the SAP connector, I suggest you use **SAP Client Extended Properties** to get full advantage of JCo additional connection parameters. These extended properties are defined in a Spring Bean and set in `jcoClientExtendedProperties` at connector or endpoint level. Take a look at the following example:

```
<spring:beans>
<spring:bean name="sapClientProperties" class="java.util.HashMap">
      <spring:constructor-arg>
          <spring:map>
              <!-- Maximum number of active connections that can be created for a destination simultaneously -->
              <spring:entry key="jco.destination.peak_limit" value="15"/>
              <!-- Maximum number of idle connections kept open by the destination. A value of 0 has the effect that there is no connection pooling, i.e. connections will be closed after each request.  -->
              <spring:entry key="jco.destination.pool_capacity" value="10"/>
              <!-- Time in ms after that the connections hold by the internal pool can be closed -->
              <spring:entry key="jco.destination.expiration_time" value="300000"/>
              <!-- Interval in ms with which the timeout checker thread checks the connections in the pool for expiration -->
              <spring:entry key="jco.destination.expiration_check_period" value="60000"/>
              <!-- Max time in ms to wait for a connection, if the max allowed number of connections is allocated by the application -->
              <spring:entry key="jco.destination.max_get_client_time" value="30000"/>
          </spring:map>
      </spring:constructor-arg>
  </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>

<sap:connector  name="SAP" 
        jcoAsHost="${sap.jcoAsHost}" 
        jcoUser="${sap.jcoUser}" 
        jcoPasswd="${sap.jcoPasswd}" 
        jcoSysnr="${sap.jcoSysnr}" 
        jcoClient="${sap.jcoClient}" 
        ...
        jcoClientExtendedProperties-ref="sapClientProperties" />
```

**Important:** to enable the pool it is mandatory that you set the `jcoExpirationTime` additionally to the Peak Limit and Pool Capacity.

For further details, please refer to [SAP Connector Advanced Features](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/sap-connector-advanced-features#jco-extended-properties) documentation.